# FCM Push notifications to multiple topics

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I has 1 issue with my project, i did subscribeToTopic(), has been successfully send 1 message to 'TopicA' and 'TopicB' like this:

```
var message = {
    data: {
      title: "title",
      body: "body"
    },
    condition: "'TopicA' in topics"
}
```

but when i send multi topics:

```
var message = {
    data: {
      title: "title",
      body: "body"
    },
    condition: "'TopicA' in topics && 'TopicB' in topics" or "'TopicA' in topics || 'TopicB' in topics"
}
```

all response success

```
"status": true,
"message": "success",
"data": "projects/{project_name}/messages/5670594709975500395"
```

but nobody received. How can i send message to 2, 3, ... topics. And how i view any message in history, my account is free. Thanks all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guees you should replace condition attribute this:

```
condition: "'TopicA' in topics && 'TopicB' in topics" or "'TopicA' in topics || 'TopicB' in topics"
```

to

```
condition: "'TopicA' in topics || 'TopicB' in topics"
```